# How can I generate all possible permutations from a Perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, permutation

I know you can generate all permutations from  a list, using [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) or [Algorithm::Permute](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Permute) for example - but how do you generate all possible permutations from a regular expression?

I want to do like:

```
@perms = permute( "/\s[A-Z][0-9][0-9]/" );
sub permute( $regex ) {
    # code - put all permutations of above regex in a list
    return @list;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Section 6.5 (PDF)](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/06InfiniteStreams.pdf) in [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/). Consider buying the print book: It is a work of art.

There is also [Regexp::Genex](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp::Genex) on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Any possibly implementation should have a reasonable maximum length in mind for the generated strings.
If there's a `+` or `*` anywhere in that regexp, the possibilities could be without end.
[Regexp::Genex](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp%3a%3aGenex) considers this.

Comment: unfortunately "perl -MRegexp::Genex=:all -le 'print for strings("[a-z]")'" does not work though. I think it has bugs with () and [] sets.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions I've encountered handle lookaheads; Regexp::Genex doesn't, nor does the solution here:

http://www.mail-archive.com/spamassassin-talk@lists.sourceforge.net/msg31051.html

While I agree that HOP is an awesome book, it's really only dealing with a small subset of regexes "out-of-the-box".

If anybody knows of one that handles lookaheads, that'd be great :/

Comment: The knapsack problem (known to be NP-complete) can trivially be translated into determining whether there exist any strings which are matched by a constructed regex (with lookaheads).  In other words, it's too hard.

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone finds it useful:

```
*$ cat bitfizz.pl*
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
if ( ($#ARGV+1)!=2 ) { print "usage $0  \n"; }
my @r = &bitfizz( $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1] );
for(@r){ print "$_\n"; }
sub bitfizz() {
    $_[0]=join( ",", split(//, $_[0] ) );
    for( my $i=1; $i<=$_[1]; $i+=1 ) { $_=$_."{$_[0]}"; } 
    @r=glob( $_ );
}
```

then you can do:

```
*perl bitfizz.pl "01" 8*
00000000
00000001
00000010
00000011
00000100
--snip--
```

all permutations of a byte in bits
or

```
*perl bitfizz.pl "0123456789ABCDEF" 2*
```

for example